# How do you validate a binary search tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I read on here of an exercise in interviews known as validating a binary search tree.

How exactly does this work? What would one be looking for in validating a binary search tree? I have written a basic search tree, but never heard of this concept.

Comment: Use inorder traversal, and check if each element is greater than the previous element.

Answer (score 117):

Actually that is the mistake everybody does in an interview.

Leftchild must be checked against (minLimitof node, node.value)

Rightchild must be checked against (node.value, MaxLimit of node)

```
IsValidBST(root,-infinity,infinity);

bool IsValidBST(BinaryNode node, int MIN, int MAX) 
{
     return node == null
         || (node.element > MIN 
         && node.element < MAX
         && IsValidBST(node.left,MIN,node.element)
         && IsValidBST(node.right,node.element,MAX));
}
```

Another solution (if space is not a constraint):
Do an inorder traversal of the tree and store the node values in an array. If the array is in sorted order, its a valid BST otherwise not.

Comment: "Another solution(if space is not a constraint) Do an inorder traversal of the tree and store the node values in an array. If the array is in sorted order, its a valid BST otherwise not."... Well you don't need _space_ or an array to do that. If you can do the traversal in the first place, and the array that you would create should be sorted, then each element that you visit during the traversal must be greater (or, in the limit case, equal) to the previous one, right?

Comment: Yes. I agree with that. but still we need one global variable to assign and access the previous value in the recursive calls. and its better than my previous example passing (MIN,MAX) on each call and eat up space on stack.

Thanks

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong... as if you have a tree with one root of value: 2 and one right child with value: 2, you will say it isn't a BST, when in fact it is.

Comment: @Yarneo A valid BST contains no duplicate nodes so I believe this algorithm is correct: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree

Comment: @DanielDaranas can you tell me the runtime of this algorithm?

Comment: It won't pass the leetcode new online test. Change the int MIN/MAX to BinaryNode null then assign node to compare will help.

Comment: This code just works. It's simple, short, concise. I don't understand all of these remarks.

Answer (score 19):

"Validating" a binary search tree means that you check that it does indeed have all smaller items on the left and large items on the right. Essentially, it's a check to see if a binary tree is a binary **search** tree.

Comment: I'm surprised that on a question that asks "What would one be looking for in validating a binary search tree?", the only answer that answers the question asked (this one) has so few votes, while answers that give code without even defining the problem have so many.

Answer (score 16):

The best solution I found is O(n) and it uses no extra space. It is similar to inorder traversal but instead of storing it to array and then checking whether it is sorted we can take a static variable and check while inorder traversing whether array is sorted.

```
static struct node *prev = NULL;

bool isBST(struct node* root)
{
    // traverse the tree in inorder fashion and keep track of prev node
    if (root)
    {
        if (!isBST(root->left))
          return false;

        // Allows only distinct valued nodes
        if (prev != NULL && root->data <= prev->data)
          return false;

        prev = root;

        return isBST(root->right);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Question: if I am not mistaken your algorithm actually takes O(n) space because of the call stack due to recursivity.
Am I missing something? Nevertheless, it's very simple!

Comment: Actually, the space complexity of your algorithm may be O(log n) for a balanced tree [as mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546611/space-complexity-of-validation-of-a-binary-search-tree/21546734#21546734).

Comment: I tried modifying this without using static variable, but could not! What do you think ? Thanks

Comment: `uses no extra space` but for recursive calls.

Comment: @PranavNandan: `tried [without] static variable, but [couldn't!?]` you need to specify a language to indicate the mechanisms available. With Java, an [atomic Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html#package.description) parameter would seem an option for most primitive keys. In terms of this answer, `bool isBST(struct node const* root, struct node * prev)` should do, with a dummy node allocated (and specified …) in `bool isBST(struct node* root)`.

Comment: Can we really do better than O(n)? We have to go to each node to validate if that subtree is a proper binary search tree or not. That makes it O(n) in worst case.

Answer (score 7):

Iterative solution using inorder traversal.

```
bool is_bst(Node *root) {
  if (!root)
    return true;

  std::stack<Node*> stack;
  bool started = false;
  Node *node = root;
  int prev_val;

  while(true) {
    if (node) {
      stack.push(node);
      node = node->left();
      continue;
    }
    if (stack.empty())
      break;
    node = stack.top();
    stack.pop();

    /* beginning of bst check */
    if(!started) {
      prev_val = node->val();
      started = true;
    } else {
      if (prev_val > node->val())
        return false;
      prev_val = node->val();
    }
    /* end of bst check */

    node = node->right();
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Good note to point out from your solution is that recursive solutions can sometimes be bad news on a production instance if you smash the stack

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution in Clojure:

```
(defstruct BST :val :left :right)

(defn in-order [bst]
  (when-let [{:keys [val, left, right]} bst]
    (lazy-seq
      (concat (in-order left) (list val) (in-order right)))))

(defn is-strictly-sorted? [col]
  (every?
    (fn [[a b]] (< a  b))
    (partition 2 1 col)))

(defn is-valid-BST [bst]
  (is-strictly-sorted? (in-order bst)))
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the in-order traversal of a BST is a non-decrease sequence, we could use this property to judge whether a binary tree is BST or not. Using [Morris traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Morris_in-order_traversal_using_threading) and maintaining the `pre` node, we could get a solution in **O(n) time and O(1) space** complexity. Here is my code

```
public boolean isValidBST(TreeNode root) {
    TreeNode pre = null, cur = root, tmp;
    while(cur != null) {
        if(cur.left == null) {
            if(pre != null && pre.val >= cur.val) 
                return false;
            pre = cur;
            cur = cur.right;
        }
        else {
            tmp = cur.left;
            while(tmp.right != null && tmp.right != cur)
                tmp = tmp.right;
            if(tmp.right == null) { // left child has not been visited
                tmp.right = cur;
                cur = cur.left;
            }
            else { // left child has been visited already
                tmp.right = null;
                if(pre != null && pre.val >= cur.val) 
                    return false;
                pre = cur;
                cur = cur.right;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: (Being `public`, `boolean isValidBST()` *needs* a comment that it temporarily *invalidates* the tree's structure - maybe even a deprecation; and an explanation when it's OK to use it, anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

"It's better to define an invariant first. Here the invariant is -- any two sequential elements of the BST in the in-order traversal must be in strictly increasing order of their appearance (can't be equal, always increasing in in-order traversal). So solution can be just a simple in-order traversal with remembering the last visited node and comparison the current node against the last visited one to '<' (or '>')."

Answer (score 1):

```
bool BinarySearchTree::validate() {
    int minVal = -1;
    int maxVal = -1;
    return ValidateImpl(root, minVal, maxVal);
}

bool BinarySearchTree::ValidateImpl(Node *currRoot, int &minVal, int &maxVal)
{
    int leftMin = -1;
    int leftMax = -1;
    int rightMin = -1;
    int rightMax = -1;

    if (currRoot == NULL) return true;

    if (currRoot->left) {
        if (currRoot->left->value < currRoot->value) {
            if (!ValidateImpl(currRoot->left, leftMin, leftMax)) return false;
            if (leftMax != currRoot->left->value && currRoot->value < leftMax)  return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    } else {
        leftMin = leftMax = currRoot->value;
    }

    if (currRoot->right) {
        if (currRoot->right->value > currRoot->value) {
            if(!ValidateImpl(currRoot->right, rightMin, rightMax)) return false;
            if (rightMin != currRoot->right->value && currRoot->value > rightMin)  return false;
        }
        else return false;
    } else {
        rightMin = rightMax = currRoot->value;
    }

    minVal = leftMin < rightMin ? leftMin : rightMin;
    maxVal = leftMax > rightMax ? leftMax : rightMax;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this question in a phone interview recently and struggled with it more than I should have. I was trying to keep track of minimums and maximums in child nodes and I just couldn't wrap my brain around the different cases under the pressure of an interview.

After thinking about it while falling asleep last night, I realized that it is as simple as keeping track of the last node you've visited during an inorder traversal. In Java:

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean isBst(TreeNode<T> root) {
    return isBst(root, null);
}

private <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean isBst(TreeNode<T> node, TreeNode<T> prev) {
    if (node == null)
        return true;

    if (isBst(node.left, prev) && (prev == null || prev.compareTo(node) < 0 ))
        return isBst(node.right, node);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Only "half right": catches "low nodes" in right subtrees, misses "high nodes" on the left (doesn't even try and propagate "rightmost/highest" values back up). For a successful implementation, albeit using a "global" variable, see [Aayush Bahuguna's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10909724/3789665),

Answer (score 1):

In Java and allowing nodes with same value in either sub-tree:

```
public boolean isValid(Node node) {
    return isValid(node, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}

private boolean isValid(Node node, int minLimit, int maxLimit) {
    if (node == null)
        return true;
    return minLimit <= node.value && node.value <= maxLimit
            && isValid(node.left, minLimit, node.value)
            && isValid(node.right, node.value, maxLimit);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer in Python, it has all the corner cases addressed and well tested in **hackerrank website**

```
# Node is defined as
class node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

```
def checkBST(root):
    return checkLeftSubTree(root, root.left) and checkRightSubTree(root, root.right)
        
def checkLeftSubTree(root, subTree):
    if not subTree:
        return True
    else:
        return root.data > subTree.data \
        and checkLeftSubTree(root, subTree.left) \ 
        and checkLeftSubTree(root, subTree.right) \
        and checkLeftSubTree(subTree, subTree.left) \
        and checkRightSubTree(subTree, subTree.right)
    
def checkRightSubTree(root, subTree):
    if not subTree:
        return True
    else:
        return root.data < subTree.data \ 
        and checkRightSubTree(root, subTree.left) \
        and checkRightSubTree(root, subTree.right) \
        and checkRightSubTree(subTree, subTree.right) \
        and checkLeftSubTree(subTree, subTree.left)
```

Comment: @user16217248: you turned a documentation string into something else: Why?

Answer (score 0):

Recursive solution:

```
isBinary(root)
    {
        if root == null 
          return true
       else if( root.left == NULL and root.right == NULL)
          return true
       else if(root.left == NULL)
           if(root.right.element > root.element)
               rerturn isBInary(root.right)
        else if (root.left.element < root.element)
              return isBinary(root.left)
        else
              return isBInary(root.left) and isBinary(root.right)

    }
```

Comment: When would it return false?

Comment: This wouldn't even return `true` if syntax was checked before execution: `rerturn` and `isBInary` should prevent that. No language is mentioned, indentation is inconsistent, there seem to be paths to the end of the block/function without explicit return (which is where a python function without an explicit return would return `None`, interpreted as `False` in a "boolean context".) Probably worse, it shows the most common error: ((.1(.3.))2.) is *not* a valid search tree, but would pass tests *if there is a left (right) subtree, it's root element must be smaller(larger) than this* tried above.

Comment: what if the left -> right element is greater than the root. In that case, the above function returns true where it should be false.

Answer (score 0):

```
// using inorder traverse based Impl
bool BinarySearchTree::validate() {
    int val = -1;
    return ValidateImpl(root, val);
}

// inorder traverse based Impl
bool BinarySearchTree::ValidateImpl(Node *currRoot, int &val) {
    if (currRoot == NULL) return true;

    if (currRoot->left) {
        if (currRoot->left->value > currRoot->value) return false;
        if(!ValidateImpl(currRoot->left, val)) return false;
    }

    if (val > currRoot->value) return false;
    val = currRoot->value;

    if (currRoot->right) {
        if (currRoot->right->value < currRoot->value) return false;
        if(!ValidateImpl(currRoot->right, val)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool ValidateBST(Node *pCurrentNode, int nMin = INT_MIN, int nMax = INT_MAX)
{
    return
    (
        pCurrentNode == NULL
    )
    ||
    (
        (
            !pCurrentNode->pLeftNode ||
            (
                pCurrentNode->pLeftNode->value < pCurrentNode->value &&
                pCurrentNode->pLeftNode->value < nMax &&
                ValidateBST(pCurrentNode->pLeftNode, nMin, pCurrentNode->value)
            )
        )
        &&
        (
            !pCurrentNode->pRightNode ||
            (
                pCurrentNode->pRightNode->value > pCurrentNode->value &&
                pCurrentNode->pRightNode->value > nMin &&
                ValidateBST(pCurrentNode->pRightNode, pCurrentNode->value, nMax)
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: My intention is to show another solution where the recursion _doesn't_ go into a branch unless it's valid. The current top answer _must_ go into a branch to check it's validity...

Comment: *If* the "2nd checks of 3" where changed to `nMin < pCurrentNode->pLeftNode->value` and `pCurrentNode->pRightNode->value < nMax`, this was just overly complicated instead of "almost right".

Answer (score 0):

To find out whether given BT is BST for any datatype, you need go with below approach.
1. call recursive function till the end of leaf node using inorder traversal
2. Build your min and max values yourself.

Tree element must have less than / greater than operator defined.

```
#define MIN (FirstVal, SecondVal) ((FirstVal) < (SecondVal)) ? (FirstVal):(SecondVal)
#define MAX (FirstVal, SecondVal) ((FirstVal) > (SecondVal)) ? (FirstVal):(SecondVal)

template <class T>
bool IsValidBST (treeNode &root)
{

   T min,  max;
   return IsValidBST (root, &min, &max);
}

template <class T>
bool IsValidBST (treeNode *root, T *MIN , T *MAX)
{
   T leftMin, leftMax, rightMin, rightMax;
   bool isValidBST;

   if (root->leftNode == NULL && root->rightNode == NULL)
   {
      *MIN = root->element;
      *MAX = root->element;
      return true;
   }

  isValidBST = IsValidBST (root->leftNode, &leftMin, &leftMax);

  if (isValidBST)
    isValidBST = IsValidBST (root->rightNode, &rightMin, &rightMax);

  if (isValidBST)
  {
     *MIN = MIN (leftMIN, rightMIN);
     *Max = MAX (rightMax, leftMax);
  }

  return isValidBST;
}
```

Comment: Probably should fix up your code -- you've made pre-processor macros of MIN and MAX, but then try to use MIN and MAX as variable (parameter) names.

Comment: `you need go with below approach` - no: for a bottom-up approach, see `isBSTDivideAndConquer()` in [Lei Cao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32984413/3789665).

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isBST(struct node* root)
{
    static struct node *prev = NULL;
    // traverse the tree in inorder fashion and keep track of prev node
    if (root)
    {
        if (!isBST(root->left))
            return false;
        // Allows only distinct valued nodes
        if (prev != NULL && root->data <= prev->data)
            return false;
        prev = root;
        return isBST(root->right);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Works Fine :)

Comment: This doesn't work if you call it more than once, and it's also not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is easy but iterative approach is better, there is one iterative version above but it's way too complex than necessary. Here is the **best** solution in `c++` you'll ever find anywhere:

This algorithm runs in `O(N)` time and needs `O(lgN)` space.

```
struct TreeNode
{
    int value;
    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right;
};

bool isBST(TreeNode* root) {
    vector<TreeNode*> stack;
    TreeNode* prev = nullptr;
    while (root || stack.size()) {
        if (root) {
           stack.push_back(root);
           root = root->left;
        } else {
            if (prev && stack.back()->value <= prev->value)
                return false;
            prev = stack.back();
            root = prev->right;                    
            stack.pop_back();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think it does, can you construct a counter example?

Comment: Trivially: a two node tree that has the same integer in "value" of both nodes will still have your isBST() function returning "true". Since you're only returning false when value < value, you'll never detect it. Why do you think that test works to find duplicates?

Comment: I thought duplicates are allowed in BST, but wikipedia seems to be against it. Then you're right, the < should be <=.

Comment: Using <= means that no node can have INT_MIN as its value.

Comment: Well.. you're right, I hope you won't be my interviewer.. :P Fixable by a extra boolean flag.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a solution to use inorder Traversal BST and check whether the nodes is 
increasing order for space `O(1)` AND time `O(n)`. `TreeNode predecessor` is prev node. I am not sure the solution is right or not. Because the  inorder Traversal can not define a whole tree.

```
public boolean isValidBST(TreeNode root, TreeNode predecessor) {
    boolean left = true, right = true;
    if (root.left != null) {
        left = isValidBST(root.left, predecessor);
    }
    if (!left)
        return false;

    if (predecessor.val > root.val)
        return false;

    predecessor.val = root.val;
    if (root.right != null) {
        right = isValidBST(root.right, predecessor);
    }

    if (!right)
        return false;

    return true;

}
```

Comment: `space O(1)` ignoring call stack - for a "true O(1) space" "solution", see [use 36805's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26443551/3789665).

Answer (score 0):

Following is the Java implementation of BST validation, where we travel the tree in-order DFS and it returns false if we get any number which is greater than last number.

```
static class BSTValidator {
  private boolean lastNumberInitialized = false;
  private int lastNumber = -1;

  boolean isValidBST(TreeNode node) {
    if (node.left != null && !isValidBST(node.left)) return false;

    // In-order visiting should never see number less than previous
    // in valid BST.
    if (lastNumberInitialized && (lastNumber > node.getData())) return false;
    if (!lastNumberInitialized) lastNumberInitialized = true;

    lastNumber = node.getData();

    if (node.right != null && !isValidBST(node.right)) return false;

    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: (`private Integer lastNumber;` would seem a viable, but not entirely equivalent alternative.)

Answer (score 0):

Iterative solution.

```
private static boolean checkBst(bst node) {

    Stack<bst> s = new Stack<bst>();
    bst temp;
    while(node!=null){
        s.push(node);
        node=node.left;
    }
    while (!s.isEmpty()){
        node = s.pop();
        System.out.println(node.val);
        temp = node;
        if(node.right!=null){
            node = node.right;
            while(node!=null)
            {
                //Checking if the current value is lesser than the previous value and ancestor.
                if(node.val < temp.val)
                    return false;
                if(!s.isEmpty())
                    if(node.val>s.peek().val)
                        return false;
                s.push(node);
                if(node!=null)
                node=node.left;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for duplicates.

```
// time O(n), space O(logn)
// pseudocode
is-bst(node, min = int.min, max = int.max):
    if node == null:
        return true
    if node.value <= min || max < node.value:
        return false
    return is-bst(node.left, min, node.value)
        && is-bst(node.right, node.value, max)
```

This works even for `int.min` and `int.max` values using `Nullable` types.

```
// time O(n), space O(logn)
// pseudocode
is-bst(node, min = null, max = null):
    if node == null:
        return true
    if min != null && node.value <= min
        return false
    if max != null && max < node.value:
        return false
    return is-bst(node.left, min, node.value)
        && is-bst(node.right, node.value, max)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by http://www.jiuzhang.com/solutions/validate-binary-search-tree/

There are two general solutions: traversal and divide && conquer.

```
public class validateBinarySearchTree {
    public boolean isValidBST(TreeNode root) {
        return isBSTTraversal(root) && isBSTDivideAndConquer(root);
    }

    // Solution 1: Traversal
    // The inorder sequence of a BST is a sorted ascending list
    private int lastValue = 0; // the init value of it doesn't matter.
    private boolean firstNode = true;
    public boolean isBSTTraversal(TreeNode root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!isValidBST(root.left)) {
            return false;
        }

        // firstNode is needed because of if firstNode is Integer.MIN_VALUE,
        // even if we set lastValue to Integer.MIN_VALUE, it will still return false
        if (!firstNode && lastValue >= root.val) {
            return false;
        }

        firstNode = false;
        lastValue = root.val;

        if (!isValidBST(root.right)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    // Solution 2: divide && conquer
    private class Result {
        int min;
        int max;
        boolean isBST;
        Result(int min, int max, boolean isBST) {
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
            this.isBST = isBST;
        }
    }

    public boolean isBSTDivideAndConquer(TreeNode root) {
        return isBSTHelper(root).isBST;
    }

    public Result isBSTHelper(TreeNode root) {
        // For leaf node's left or right
        if (root == null) {
            // we set min to Integer.MAX_VALUE and max to Integer.MIN_VALUE
            // because of in the previous level which is the leaf level,
            // we want to set the min or max to that leaf node's val (in the last return line)
            return new Result(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE, true);
        }

        Result left = isBSTHelper(root.left);
        Result right = isBSTHelper(root.right);

        if (!left.isBST || !right.isBST) {
            return new Result(0,0, false);
        }

        // For non-leaf node
        if (root.left != null && left.max >= root.val
                && root.right != null && right.min <= root.val) {
            return new Result(0, 0, false);
        }

        return new Result(Math.min(left.min, root.val),
                Math.max(right.max, root.val), true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The last two statements of `boolean isBSTTraversal()` can be combined to `return isValidBST(root.right);`. In `Result isBSTHelper()`, requiring `root.val` to be *both* no greater than `left.max` *and* no smaller than `right.min` for a "false `Result`" doesn't seem quite right.

Answer (score 0):

One liner

```
bool is_bst(Node *root, int from, int to) {
   return (root == NULL) ? true :
     root->val >= from && root->val <= to &&
     is_bst(root->left, from, root->val) &&
     is_bst(root->right, root->val, to);
}
```

Pretty long line though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in java from sedgewick's algorithm class.
Check the full BST implementation [here](https://github.com/kevin-wayne/algs4/blob/master/src/main/java/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/BST.java)

I added some explanatory comments

```
private boolean isBST() {
    return isBST(root, null, null);

}

private boolean isBST(Node x, Key min, Key max) {
    if (x == null) return true;
    // when checking right subtree min is key of x's parent
    if (min != null && x.key.compareTo(min) <= 0) return false;
    // when checking left subtree, max is key of x's parent
    if (max != null && x.key.compareTo(max) >= 0) return false;
    // check left subtree and right subtree
    return isBST(x.left, min, x.key) && isBST(x.right, x.key, max);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

- The `iterative` function checks iteratively whether given tree is a binary search tree.
- The `recurse` function checks recursively whether given tree is a binary search tree or not.
- In `iterative` function I use bfs for checking BST.
- In `recurse` function I use dfs for checking BST.
- Both solutions have a time complexity of `O(n)`
- `iterative` solution has an advantage over `recurse` solution and that is `iterative` solution does early stopping.
- Even `recurse` function can be optimized for early stopping by global flag value.
- The idea of both the solution is that the left child should be within the range of -infinity to the value of its parent node whihch is the root node
- The right child should be within the range of +infinity to the value of its parent node whihch is the root node
- And go on comparing the current node's value within the range. If any node's value is not in the range then return False

  ```
  class Solution:
      def isValidBST(self, root):
          """
          :type root: TreeNode
          :rtype: bool
          """
          return self.iterative(root)
          # return self.recurse(root, float("inf"), float("-inf"))

      def iterative(self, root):
          if not root:
              return True

          level = [[root, -float("inf"), float("inf")]]

          while level:
              next_level = []

              for element in level:
                  node, min_val, max_val = element
                  if min_val<node.val<max_val:
                      if node.left:
                          next_level.append([node.left, min_val, node.val])
                      if node.right:
                          next_level.append([node.right, node.val, max_val])
                  else:
                      return False
              level = next_level

          return True

      def recurse(self, root, maxi, mini):
          if root is None:
              return True

          if root.val < mini or root.val > maxi:
              return False

          return self.recurse(root.left, root.val-1, mini) and self.recurse(root.right, maxi, root.val+1)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Python implementation example. This example uses type annotations. However since Node class uses itself we need to include as a first line of the module:

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

Otherwise, you will get `name 'Node' is not defined` error. This example also uses dataclass as an example. To check if it's BST it uses recursion for checking left and right nodes values.

```
"""Checks if Binary Search Tree (BST) is balanced"""

from __future__ import annotations
import sys
from dataclasses import dataclass

MAX_KEY = sys.maxsize
MIN_KEY = -sys.maxsize - 1


@dataclass
class Node:
    value: int
    left: Node
    right: Node

    @property
    def is_leaf(self) -> bool:
        """Check if node is a leaf"""
        return not self.left and not self.right


def is_bst(node: Node, min_value: int, max_value: int) -> bool:
    if node.value < min_value or max_value < node.value:
        return False
    elif node.is_leaf:
        return True

    return is_bst(node.left, min_value, node.value) and is_bst(
        node.right, node.value, max_value
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    node5 = Node(5, None, None)
    node25 = Node(25, None, None)
    node40 = Node(40, None, None)
    node10 = Node(10, None, None)

    # balanced tree
    node30 = Node(30, node25, node40)
    root = Node(20, node10, node30)
    print(is_bst(root, MIN_KEY, MAX_KEY))

    # unbalanced tree
    node30 = Node(30, node5, node40)
    root = Node(20, node10, node30)
    print(is_bst(root, MIN_KEY, MAX_KEY))
```

Answer (score 0):

BST example
[image]

```
    public bool IsBinarySearchTree(TreeNode root)
    {
        return IsValid(root, long.MinValue, long.MaxValue);
    }

    private static bool IsValid(TreeNode node, long min, long max)
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (node.Value >= max || node.Value <= min)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return IsValid(node.Left, min, node.Value) && IsValid(node.Right, node.Value, max);
    }
```

where `TreeNode`

```
   public class TreeNode
   {
       public int Value;
       public TreeNode Left;
       public TreeNode Right;

       public TreeNode(int value)
       {
           Value = value;
       }
   }
```

here's the detailed explanation https://codestandard.net/articles/validate-binary-search-tree/

Answer (score 0):

We have to recursively ask each node if its left branch and right branch are valid binary search trees. The only thing each time we ask, we have to pass correct left and right boundaries:

[image]

```
class Solution:
    def is_bst(self,root:TreeNode):
        if not root:
            return True
        # left and right are boundaries
        def dfs(node,left,right):
            if not node:
                return True
            if not (node.val>left and node.val<right):
                return False
            # when we move right, we update the left, when we move left we update the right
            return dfs(node.left,left,node.val) and dfs(node.right,node.val,right)
        return dfs(root, float("-inf"), float("+inf"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using inOrder Traversal..

First Adding the tree value to the array with inorder traversal.

Then iterate through the array which add a flag value true to split the elements after the root elements and before the root elements.

counter is added to check if the tree has elements with the same root value.

min and max is set to the range

```
var isValidBST = function(root) 
{

    
    if(!root) return false;
    
 
    let current = root;
    let data = [];
    let flag = false;
    let counter = 0;
    
    function check(node){
        if(node.left){
            check(node.left);
        }
        data.push(node.val);
        if(node.right){
            check(node.right);
        }
       
    }
    
    
    let min = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;
    let max = root.val;
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        
        if(data[i] == root.val){
            flag = true;
            counter++;
        }
        
        if(flag){
            if(data[i] < root.val || data[i] < max || counter > 1){
                return false;
            }
            else{
                
                max = data[i];
            }
            
            
        }
        else{
            if(data[i] > root.val || data[i] <= min|| counter > 1){
                return false
            }
            else {
                min = data[i]
            }
        }
    }
    
    return true;
    

};
```

Comment: Why special case `root.val`? Why handle values "before" `root.val` any different from those after?

Comment: root.val is to identify the values before the root elements. Inorder traversal gives you an array of tree elements in ascending order. So all elements before root.val should be lesser and values after root should be greater.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the iterative solution without using extra space.

```
Node{
     int value;
     Node right, left
  }

  public boolean ValidateBST(Node root){
    Node currNode = root;
    Node prevNode = null;
    Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();
    while(true){
        if(currNode != null){
            stack.push(currNode);
            currNode = currNode.left;
            continue;
        }
        if(stack.empty()){
            return;
        }
        currNode = stack.pop();
        if(prevNode != null){
            if(currNode.value < prevNode.value){
                return false;
            }
        }
        prevNode = currNode;
        currNode = currNode.right;
    }
}
```

Comment: Iterative solution without using extra space? But you're using a stack here and do `stack.push()`!

Answer (score -1):

```
 private void validateBinarySearchTree(Node node) {
    if (node == null) return;

    Node left = node.getLeft();
    if (left != null) {
        if (left.getData() < node.getData()) {
            validateBinarySearchTree(left);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Not a valid Binary Search tree");
        }
    }

    Node right = node.getRight();
    if (right != null) {
        if (right.getData() > node.getData()) {
            validateBinarySearchTree(right);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Not a valid Binary Search tree");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
boolean isBST(Node root) {
    if (root == null) { return true; }
    return (isBST(root.left) && (isBST(root.right) && (root.left == null || root.left.data <= root.data) && (root.right == null || root.right.data > root.data));
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is my recursive solution written in JavaScript

```
function isBST(tree) {
  if (tree === null) return true;

  if (tree.left != undefined && tree.left.value > tree.value) {
    return false;
  }

  if (tree.right != undefined && tree.right.value <= tree.value) {
    return false;
  }

  return isBST(tree.left) && isBST(tree.right);
}
```