# Space complexity of validation of a binary search tree

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, binary-search-tree

The best algorithm to verify if a binary tree is a BST is given as follows

```
IsValidBST(root,-infinity,infinity);

bool IsValidBST(BinaryNode node, int MIN, int MAX) 
{
    if(node == null)
        return true;
    if(node.element > MIN 
        && node.element < MAX
        && IsValidBST(node.left,MIN,node.element)
        && IsValidBST(node.right,node.element,MAX))
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

The space complexity of this logic is apparently `O(logN)` which I'm assuming is the cost of recursion. How was the value arrived at?

Comment: There is no additional data used other than the method variables and the return value, so indeed, all memory is "cost of recursion". The total cost would hence be linearly proportional to the depth of the tree. In a *balanced binary search tree*, the depth is `O(log n)`, so indeed, the space complexity would be `O(log n)` too. However, in general a BST is not necessarily balanced, it could even be a chain of length `n`, if the root is the minimum, its right child is the second smallest element, and so on. In that case the space complexity of this recursion is `O(n)`.

Comment: @Heuster Good comment, but it should really be the answer.

Comment: How is the question related to c or c++? Does it matter in any way here what language you use?

Comment: @user694733 I guess you're right :-)

Comment: And for what its worth, the author should have a const-reference param regardless.

Comment: Basically: a binary tree that is put together nicely results in slicing searches: You start at the root, and determine weather to look left, or right, excluding half of the tree already. You continue like this until you get what you need. Depending on the _depth_ rather then total nodes of the tree, a search will be faster/slower. While O(n) is possible, the more nodes you add, the more unlikely O(n) becomes

Comment: Note: it can be done in O(1) if each node has a pointer to its parent, because you can then iterate without maintaining a stack. So it fairly depends on *how* the binary tree is represented.

Comment: The space complexity is O(h) where h is the length of the longest path from root to leaf. That's not necessarily O(lg n) where n is the number of nodes.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Wouldn't you still need storage for keeping information about where you are in the search?  E.g., you've just backtracked to a parent node: how do you then know whether the 'right' node still needs searching?  If you're allowed to mark the nodes as "visited" somehow I can see how this would work, but what if the nodes aren't writable?

Comment: @MarkDickinson: All you need to know when back-tracking, is knowing whether you are coming from the left child (so next is the right child) or coming from the right child (so next is up). Well, this only requires a boolean: before back-tracking, check whether you are the left or right child, then back-track "from left" or "from right".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My comment upgraded to answer:

There is no additional data used other than the method variables and the return value, so indeed, all memory is "cost of recursion". The total cost would hence be linearly proportional to the depth of the tree.

In a *balanced binary search tree*, the depth is `O(log n)`, so indeed, the space complexity would be `O(log n)` too. However, in general a BST is not necessarily balanced, it could even be a chain of length n, if the root is the minimum, its right child is the second smallest element, and so on. In that case the space complexity of this recursion is `O(n)`.

Comment: but aren't you adding one entry to the recursive stack for each node? isn't that O(n) regardless of how the BST is constructed?

Comment: The stack is cleaned up when the recursive function reaches a leaf node. So if the tree is balanced, the stack will never be deeper than log n.

Comment: Thank you, but we have elements on both sides of the BST, so why it's `O(log n)` please?

Comment: @avra, see Mats' comment above yours. Elements are popped from the stack on the way "up", so the size of the stack doesn't exceed the depth of the tree.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele. Thank you very much! So last question is, why we should have complexity of `O(log n)` when we do check each left and right subtree at each node? If we have `n` nodes, then we should have `O(nlog n)` compelxity for checking validity of BST, please correct if I am wrong? (This is for bruteforce solution not for the above).

Comment: @Avra I'm not sure why that would have `O(n log n)` space complexity. Could it be that you are talking about time complexity instead?

Comment: Yes I am talking about time complexity

Comment: Please post that as a new question then :) Comments are only intended for clarifying the current question/answer.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele. Thank you. So sticking to space complexity, what if the tree is unbalanced? Then in that case, the stack size would be `O(n)` and so the space complexity?