# Is this a valid binary search tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree

```
      10
     /  \
    /    \
   9      13
  / \ 
 /   \
5    12
```

If No, why ?
If yes, why inorder traversal (5,9,12,10,13) on this don't results in a sorted sequence of nodes ?

Note: The leaf 5 is left child of 9 and leaf 12 is right child of 9.

Comment: 10 and 12 is wrong.. 12 is greater than 10.. so it should be the root.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you validate a binary search tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499995/how-do-you-validate-a-binary-search-tree)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not a valid search tree. While it's *balanced* (difference between highest and lowest leaf is one or less), the ordering of the `10` and `12` is incorrect.

It would be valid if it were:

```
     12
    /  \
   /    \
  9      13
 / \
5   10
```

The basic rule is that everything in the entire left sub-tree of a node should be lesser than that node's value. And, accordingly, everything in the right sub-tree should be greater.

Clearly `12` is *not* less than `10` so your given tree is not much good as a binary search tree. If you went looking for `12`, the first thing you would do from the root node is to descend into the *right* sub-tree, where you wouldn't be able to find it.

You can validate a binary search tree with the following recursive pseudo-code:

```
def isValid (node):
    # Gone below leaf, so is valid.

    if node == NULL:
        return true

    # Check immediate children if they're there.

    if node.left <> NULL:
        if node.value < node.left.value:
            return false

    if node.right <> NULL:
        if node.value > node.right.value:
            return false

    # Check individual sub-trees (both must be valid).

    if not isValid (node.left):
        return false

    return isValid (node.right)
```

and call it with the root node:

```
wholeTreeValid = isValid (root)
```

Comment: I assumed that we only consider the only left and right child for comparison. However, the fact is we should consider all nodes in child subtree for comparisons.