# Checking if a Binary Search Tree is Valid javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I came across this problem online and I found the following function to check if a BST is valid. However, what I don't fully understand is how max/min change from null to values that you can compare against.  so in the following function:

```
//Give the recursive function starting values:

 function checkBST(node) {
  // console.log(node.right);
  return isValidBST(node, null, null);
}


 function isValidBST(node, min, max) {
  console.log(min, max);


  if (node === null) {

    return true;
  }

  if ((max !== null && node.val > max) || (min !== null && node.val < min)) {

    return false;
  }

  if (!isValidBST(node.left, min, node.val) || !isValidBST(node.right, node.val, max)) {

    return false;
  }
  return true;
}



var bst = new BinarySearchTree(8);
bst.insert(3);
bst.insert(1);
bst.insert(6);
bst.insert(10);
bst.insert(4);
```

when you come back up from the lowest depth on the left it compares the value at the lowest depth with the depth right above it (ie when  1 3 is output). somehow min goes from null to 1 and I'm not seeing how, I was thinking you would need some sort of a base case for the minimum to change from null to something else...
I get this in the console when I console.log min/max on each run.

```
null null
null 8
null 3
null 1
1 3
3 8
3 6
3 4
4 6
6 8
8 null
8 10
10 null
```

Comment: you are explicitly calling isValidBST with non null values with this expression `if (!isValidBST(node.left, min, node.val) || !isValidBST(node.right, node.val, max)) {
`

Comment: Right, but how? How does min become a non null value?

Comment: Because you pass in node.val `isValidBST(node.right, node.val, max)` so node.val must not be null.

Comment: Everything you ever wanted to know about this is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499995/how-do-you-validate-a-binary-search-tree

Comment: @bhspencer oh I think I get it now.  those two separate function calls know about each other's variables (min, max), I think that's what was tripping me up. feel free to post as answer and I will accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `min` becomes non null because you explicitly call

`isValidBST(node.right, node.val, max)`

where you are passing node.val as the param `min`. It must be that at the point you make this call `node.val` is not null;

Answer (score 3):

Given a node, validate the binary search tree,
ensuring that every node's left hand child is
less than the parent node's value, and that
every node's right hand child is greater than
the parent

```
class Node {
constructor(data) {
this.data = data;
this.left = null;
this.right = null;
 }
}

class Tree {
 constructor() {
 this.root = null;
}

isValidBST(node, min = null, max = null) {
if (!node) return true;
if (max !== null && node.data >= max) {
  return false;
}
if (min !== null && node.data <= min) {
  return false;
}
const leftSide = this.isValidBST(node.left, min, node.data);
const rightSide = this.isValidBST(node.right, node.val, max);

return leftSide && rightSide;
}
}

const t = new Node(10);
t.left = new Node(0);
t.left.left = new Node(7);
t.left.right = new Node(4);
t.right = new Node(12);
const t1 = new Tree();
t1.root = t;
console.log(t1.isValidBST(t));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be:

```
const isValidBST = (
  root,
  min = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER,
  max = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
) => {
  if (root == null) return true;
  if (root.val >= max || root.val <= min) return false;
  return (
    isValidBST(root.left, min, root.val) &&
    isValidBST(root.right, root.val, max)
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking if a Binary Search Tree is Valid:

```js
class BTNode {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  }
}

/**
 *
 * @param {BTNode} tree
 * @returns {Boolean}
 */
const isBinarySearchTree = (tree) => {
  if (tree) {
    if (
      tree.left &&
      (tree.left.value > tree.value || !isBinarySearchTree(tree.left))
    ) {
      return false;
    }
    if (
      tree.right &&
      (tree.right.value <= tree.value || !isBinarySearchTree(tree.right))
    ) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};
```